# Hiding same accordion panel on click jQuery

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am using a JQuery accordion, everything seems to work fine except for when you click on the active panel it slides up and back down.

When I click on the active panel I need it to hide, but if I select a new panel I need it to slide up hiding the old active panel, and then back down displaying the newly selected panel.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab-panels .tabs li').click(function(){
        var panel = $(this).closest('.tab-panels');

        panel.find('.tabs li .active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var panelToShow = $(this).attr('rel');

        panel.find('.panel.active').slideUp(500, nextPanel);

        function nextPanel() {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $('#'+panelToShow).slideDown(500, function(){
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
        }

        });

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x1zw352t/41/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is using your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/austinthedeveloper/x1zw352t/42/

The trick is to have a conditional statement surrounding your slideUp function:

```
if ($('#' + panelToShow).hasClass('active')) {
  panel.find('.panel.active').slideUp(500);
} else {
  panel.find('.panel.active').slideUp(500, nextPanel);
}
```

I also added a standard .active class to make sure the first one shows:

```
div.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Here is an alternative method where the conditional statement is actually inside of the nextPanel function: http://jsfiddle.net/austinthedeveloper/x1zw352t/43/

Comment: A few issues with that. The first is the fact that it doesn't remove the active class from the li which is a function I still need. The second is if clicked on the same one it doesn't show again after it hides.